# Who has received a letter about energy?

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

Four administrators (A, B, C, and D) from a company have written letters about four topics: Energy, Security, Nutrition, and Manpower. Each letter has a unique topic, sender, and receiver.

Information:

- the admin who has sent a letter about nutrition has received a letter about security from **A**.
- the letter which has been sent by **B** has been received *not* by **D**.
- the letter which has been received by **D** wasn't about nutrition.
- none of the two admins have written letters to each other (for example, we don't have "B to A" if we have "A to B").

Question: If the letter about manpower has been sent by D, which admin has received the letter about energy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be easy enough even without building a formal grid:

> * **D** didn't receive the security letter (nutrition letter writer did, D wrote about manpower)
>  * **D** didn't receive the nutrition letter (says so in point 3)
>  * **D** didn't receive the manpower letter (he wrote it)

So as long as I've correctly understood the uniqueness rules,

> **D** must have received the letter about energy.